# What are the risk of allowing users to embeed my page in an iframe?

Tags: html, security, iframe, browser

I'm thinking to allow users to embeed a specific **section** of a page of my site inside an iframe by providing the code myself. It will be just that page which is meant to show something interesting to the audience that my site targets. I don't know any other way of doing that but giving them a code like this:

```
<iframe src='A' width='B' height='C' frameborder='D'></iframe>
```

Where 'A' is the page embeeded inside the `iframe` and 'B', 'C' and 'D' are optional parameters so the users can perform some customization.

'A' is not the page from where the users will get the code. 'A' is a clone of the page that some users will eventually want to embeed in their site. In simple words, 'A' is just a **section** of that page... in a complete different page.

But I don't know what kind of risk, if any, that would suppose for me. Or if there is another way to approaching what I want. Or how to allow users to embeed only that page but not the rest of the pages.

Is ok what I'm doing or am I missing here with some basic security stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers are pretty locked down on what can be accessed in an iframe with a source from a different origin. They won't have access to any DOM objects, url or js in the embedded page.

You can lock down what pages can be be put in an iframe using http headers.

Pages you don't want iframed
`X-Frame-Options: DENY`

Pages you only want to iframed
`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

Pages you only want iframed by a certain uri (not supported in Chrome, Opera)
`X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM uri`

Source
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Thank you @Louisa Buchanan If that is only I need, it's ok then.